# Why assign values to C-contiguous array is slow in my case using Cython

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

I got a problem of assigning temporary results to an array using Cython. Here I declare a `test_array`, `sample-size` and `weight_array`, and by using `for` loop, I save each weighted result into a `res_array`. Both `test_array` and `weight_array` are defined as C-contiguous arrays in Cython. The test.pyx and setup.py files are listed as follows:

```
# test.pyx
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import random
cimport cython
from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.profile(True)
def cython_sample(int res_size, int sample_size, double[::1] all_data, double[::1] weight_array):
    # using c-contiguous array can speed up a little bit
    cdef int ii, jj
    cdef double tmp_res, dot_result
    cdef double[::1] tmp_sample = np.ones(sample_size, dtype=np.double)
    cdef double[::1] res_array = np.ones(res_size, dtype=np.double)

    ran = random.normalvariate   # generate random value as a test
    for ii in range(res_size):
        tmp_sample = all_data[ii:(ii + sample_size)]

        # inner product operation
        dot_result = 0.0
        for jj in range(sample_size):
            dot_result += tmp_sample[jj]*weight_array[jj]

        # save inner product result into array 
        res_array[ii] = dot_result
        #res_array[ii] = ran(10000,20000)

     return res_array

# setup.py
from setuptools import setup,find_packages
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

ext = Extension("mycython.test", sources=["mycython/test.pyx"])
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(ext),
      include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
      name="mycython",     
      version="0.1",
      packages=find_packages(),
      author="me",
      author_email="me@example.com",
      url="http://example.com/")
```

And the python test.py is:

```
import time
import random
import numpy as np
from strategy1 import __cyn__

sample_size = 3000
test_array = [random.random() for _ in range(300000)]
res_size = len(test_array) - sample_size + 1
weight_array = [random.random() for _ in range(sample_size)]
c_contig_store_array = np.ascontiguousarray(test_array, dtype=np.double)
c_contig_weigh_array = np.ascontiguousarray(weight_array, dtype=np.double)


replay = 100
start_time = time.time()
for ii in range(int(replay)):
    __cyn__.cython_sample(res_size, sample_size, c_contig_store_array, c_contig_weigh_array)
per_elapsed_time = (time.time() - start_time) / replay
print('Elapse time :: %g sec' % (per_elapsed_time))
```

So I test two scenarios:

```
# 1. when saving dot_result into 'res_array':
     res_array[ii] = dot_result
```

speed test shows: `Elapse time :: 0.821084 sec`

```
# 2. when saving a random value ran(10000,20000) into 'res_array':
     res_array[ii] = ran(10000,20000)
```

speed test shows: `Elapse time :: 0.214591 sec`.

The reason that I use  `ran(*,*)` to test the codes is that I found if I comment out both `res_array[ii] = dot_result` and `res_array[ii] = ran(10000,20000)` in the original codes, the speed will almost increase 30-100 times (`Elapse time :: 0.00633394 sec`). Then I thought the issue could lie in assigning `dot_result` value to `res_array`, which turn to be true as the speed of assigning a random generated double value `ran(10000,20000)` to `res_array` is pretty fast (almost 4 times faster as shown above).

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use the value of `dot_result`, the compiler will remove the loop:

```
dot_result = 0.0
for jj in range(sample_size):
    dot_result += tmp_sample[jj]*weight_array[jj]
```

The inner loop takes most of the computing time.

You cython code seems like `correlate()`, you can speed it up by using fft:

```
from scipy import signal
res = signal.fftconvolve(c_contig_store_array, c_contig_weigh_array[::-1], mode="valid")
```

Comment: Thanks for the note! The first point is pretty cool, and I agree with it. For the signal.fftconvolve, I try it in my cython or python codes, and it hardly can speed up (for some reason it slow down) and the inner product seems to be the simplest solution as we are doing many times inner product operations on a rolling window. Do you think is there any better way speed up inner product in cython? Thanks

Comment: my sample code for `signal.fftconvolve()` returns the same result as the `cython_sample()` function. You don't need to call it in Cython. There is no inner loop if you use fft method.

Comment: Yea, I got it! Brilliant solution, it is really fast, even 17 times faster than using ***cdef extern from "cblas.h":  double ddot "cblas_ddot"(int, double *, int, double *, int)*** as indicated in http://maldun.lima-city.de/introduction_to_python/Cython.html. Your way is a pretty cool idea!